# How do you reference javascript's this keyword from clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

I'm integrating some ClojureScript code with a JS library call that takes a callback function.  The JS library passes data to the callback using JavsScript's "this" keyword.

I can get it to work using (js* "this").  For example:

```
(libraryCall (fn [] (.log console (js* "this"))))
```

Is there a way to get at the "this" context from ClojureScript without resorting to js*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the built-in `this-as` macro. It takes a name and a body, and evaluates the body with the name bound to JavaScript `this`.

e.g.

```
(libraryCall (fn [] (this-as my-this (.log js/console my-this))))
```

Great question... had to dig into the compiler code to find it, it's not well advertised at all.

I'll add it to the book.