# How to toggle class on a dom element using clojurescript or om-next

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, om, om-next

I'm new to clojurescript and I got a task of creating a filter with toggling list items requirement on click of a plus icon. I have written css to hide when the class is inactive and show when it's active. I just want to know the correct syntax how to toggle the class on click using clojurescript or om-next.

Or is there any way to toggle (empty / fill) the list array on click of sibling / other element (h3).

I have tried something like this.

```
[:h3 (:name aggregation) {:on-click #(swap! :className "dInline" "dNone")}]
```

This is the actual code.

```
(defn render-aggregation
    [{navigation-dimension :field :as aggregation} toggle-expanded rendered-filters]
        (let [show-expanded? (> (count (:values aggregation)) 8)]
            [:li {:key (str "k-" navigation-dimension)}
                 [:h3 (:name aggregation)]
                     (cond-> (into [:ul.list-unstyled] rendered-filters)
                         show-expanded?
                         (conj [:li
                             [:button.btn.btn-default.btn-xs {:on-click (toggle-expanded aggregation)}
                                 (if (:ui/expanded? aggregation) "show fewer" "show more")]]))]))
```

Actual result is h3 element should change it's class to "dNone" on click

Comment: You have to set a field in the om.next state and deref that to retrieve the className (so that om.next knows to rerender). `(swap! :className "dInline" "dNone")` does not work, since `swap!` works on an `atom`, not a keyword. Are you allowed to use [Reagent](http://reagent-project.github.io/)? I find that frontend framework easier to understand than om.next or Fulcro and can give you an example then.

Comment: Not using reagent. Can you reply with a simple code and explain briefly how to set field? On click, I have to change/toggle classname of sibling element. Currently trying to change class for the same element first.

Comment: You have to get some atom or other mutable reference (om.next state?) and then `swap!` that. `(swap! your-atom-with-state-of-the-className "dInline" "dNone")`, and then in the app you can deref that `[:h3 (:name aggregation)] {:className @your-atom-with-state-of-the-className}`. om.next should know how to rerender then. But I don't know enough about om.next how this exactly works, and I cannot get it from the documentation quickly. Maybe you can ask in #om channel in clojurians.slack.org as well?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions tapping into vanilla JS:

1. You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588947/how-to-hide-show-a-table-in-clojurescript) answer helpful. It requires the element (your
   h3) to have an ID though.
2. If you cannot hav an ID you may want to make use of JavaScript's `this` keyword, which apparently is accessible from ClojureScript (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310950/how-do-you-reference-javascripts-this-keyword-from-clojurescript))

I have successfully used method #1 in some of my exercise code, but I'm pretty new to ClojureScript and Web Development in general… please handle my answer with care.

Cheers

Oliver